# mvc form in partial view duplicates selected values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application which I use the following to output a form to the screen:

```
@foreach (CarbonFootprintHelper helper in SessionHelper.CarbonFootprint.SelectedItems)
{
    @Html.Partial("_CarbonCalculator_Form", helper)
}
```

The partial has the following code:

```
<form action="@UrlUtilities.Urls.CarbonCalculator?SelectedProductId=@SessionHelper.CarbonFootprint.LoadedProduct.ProductID" method="post" class="carbon-form">
    @Html.ValidationMessage(string.Format("error-{0}", currentIndex))

    @if (SessionHelper.CarbonFootprint.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" class="remove-button button" />
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="product-@currentIndex" class="hide-element">Product</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("footprintId", ParentList, "Please select a product", new { id = string.Format("product-{0}", currentIndex), @class = "drop-down" })
    </div>

    @if (ChildList != null)
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="child-product-@currentIndex" class="hide-element">Sub-Product</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("childFootprintId", ChildList, "Please select a sub-product", new { id = string.Format("child-product-{0}", currentIndex), @class = "drop-down" })
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="quantity-@selectedParentId" class="hide-element">Quantity</label>
        @Html.TextBox("quantity", quantity, new { id = string.Format("quantity-{0}", currentIndex), @class = "textbox" })
        @Html.Raw(Model.Message)
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.Hidden("currentIndex", currentIndex, new { id = string.Format("index-{0}", currentIndex) })
        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Which is basically just showing some dropdowns based on whether I have selected them or not.

My problem is that if I have multiple forms appended to the page, when I press the calculate button to update that form, it will change all the selected values and quantities in all the forms - even though if I step through the code it is assigning the correct values.

Does anyone know what may cause this?  I have a feeling it may be due to the inputs all having the same name.  If so how do I go about having a different name for each input but keeping only one controller - for eaxmple, the current form posts to:

```
public ActionResult CarbonCalculator(string selectedProductId, int currentIndex, int footprintId = 0, int childFootprintId = 0, int quantity = 0)
```

but if I have different input names then how do I avoid the need for a new controller per form?

Comment: I don't see your `<form>` tag. In your example you should have `<form>` tag for each block

Comment: Sorry, the form tag wraps the partial - I just haven't show it above

Comment: _when I press the calculate button to update that form_
When you press calculate it updates the whole page, not just 1 form. It sends values from the *current* form to the server, and server returns the whole page. What happens when you change Product on the second form and press 'Calculate' (on the second form)? What do you receive on the server?

Comment: it will post the same values to `CarbonCalculator` action as shown above and then I will change the session depending on the `currentIndex` variable.  The problem isn't the post, it's just that all the dropdowns and inputs are not showing their correct values.  As I have said, when I step through the loop whist the forms are being rendered, the correct values are being sent but it is only displaying the value of the last form that was updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have managed to make this work is to remove the html helpers altogether and go old school by handcoding the inputs:

```
<form action="@UrlUtilities.Urls.CarbonCalculator?SelectedProductId=@SessionHelper.CarbonFootprint.LoadedProduct.ProductID" method="post" class="carbon-form">
    @Html.ValidationMessage(string.Format("error-{0}", currentIndex))

    @if (SessionHelper.CarbonFootprint.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" class="remove-button button" />
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="product-@currentIndex" class="hide-element">Product</label>
        <select name="FootprintId" id="product-@currentIndex" class="drop-down">
            <option @Html.Raw(Model.FootprintId == 0 ? "selected=\"selected\"" : string.Empty)>Please select a product</option>
            @foreach (CarbonFootprintProduct prod in CarbonFootprint.Items.FilteredProducts)
            {
                <option value="@prod.CarbonFootprintID" @Html.Raw(Model.FootprintId == prod.CarbonFootprintID ? "selected=\"selected\"" : string.Empty)>@prod.ProductDescription</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    @if (Model.FootprintId > 0 && Model.SelectedProduct.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="child-product-@currentIndex" class="hide-element">Sub-Product</label>
            <select name="ChildFootprintId" id="child-product-@currentIndex" class="drop-down">
                <option @Html.Raw(Model.ChildFootprintId == 0 ? "selected=\"selected\"" : string.Empty)>Please select a sub-product</option>
                @foreach (CarbonFootprintChild child in Model.SelectedProduct.Children)
                {
                    <option value="@child.CarbonFootprintChildID" @Html.Raw(Model.ChildFootprintId == child.CarbonFootprintChildID ? "selected=\"selected\"" : string.Empty)>@child.Description</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="infield-holder">
            <label for="quantity-@currentIndex" title="Quantity" class="infield">Qty</label>
            <input type="text" name="Quantity" value="@quantity" class="textbox" id="quantity-@currentIndex" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.Raw(Model.Message)

    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="CurrentIndex" value="@currentIndex" id="index-@currentIndex" />
        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ahh, seems I got it. You should use DropDownListFor instead of DropDownList

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.FootprintId, ParentList, "Please select a product", new { id = string.Format("product-{0}", currentIndex), @class = "drop-down" })
```

`Model.FootprintId` should contain id of the selected Product.

Best Regards,
nZ

Comment: DropDownListFor is just so you can use the model - I tried the following but still the same error: 
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FootprintId, ParentList, "Please select a product", new { id = string.Format("product-{0}", currentIndex), @class = "drop-down" })

Comment: Does `ParentList` has an item with the Value = `Model.FootprintId`?

Comment: yes, that would be the selected option when the list is rendered